# R: Processing sequences of a large list of matrices with lapply

Tags: r, list, matrix, lapply

I have a list of 1040 big matrices. I would like to

1. Calculate the average values in each element of each matrix for the following matrices: 1-4,53-56,105-108....etc up to almost 1040 - as you can see this follows simple sequence of i, i+1, i+2, i+3 but with a step increase of 52.
2. I would like to take the mean of values 5-8, 57-60, 109-112, etc. and,
3. The mean of groups of 9-12, 61-64...etc. So in general 13 groups of 80 matrices.

I've provided a small reproducible example for taking averages of groups 1-2, 5-6, 9-10... and later 3-4, 7-8... etc, but frankly I don't know how to do it without too much laborious and manual indexing of lists and unnecessary work (which I will not be pasting below to save space and agony). I am sure `lapply()` should provide a solution.

```
NCols=5 
NRows=7 

myMat1<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
myMat2<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
myMat3<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
myMat4<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
myMat5<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
myMat6<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
myMat7<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
myMat8<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
myMat9<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
myMat10<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
myMat11<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
myMat12<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
myMat13<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
myMat14<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
myMat15<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols)
myMat16<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
myMat17<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
myMat18<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols)
myMat19<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
myMat20<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 

MyList <- list(myMat1,myMat2,myMat3,myMat4,myMat5,myMat6,myMat7,myMat8,myMat9,myMat10,
              myMat11,myMat12,myMat13,myMat14,myMat15,myMat16,myMat17,myMat18,myMat19,myMat20)
```

Comment: change the list(c(...)) to just list(...) for your example - otherwise you will just have a vector not matrices

Comment: `set.seed(1); my_list <- replicate(20, list(matrix(runif(5 * 7), 5, 7))); means <- sapply(split(my_list, rep(seq(length(my_list) / 2), each = 2)), function(x){mean(unlist(x))}); means[c(TRUE, FALSE)]; means[c(FALSE, TRUE)]`

Comment: "The horror! The horror!” : Don't construct related objects in the global environment. Make then all list elements and then .... First accession with `lapply( seq(1, 1040, by = 52), "+", 0:3)`. Or use sapply if appropriate to you needs.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. However I still don't know how to create a loop that will call groups of elements in the sequence that I am after. @42 gives piece of the puzzle, but still it is not complete. thanks so much for your time